# how to run sudo command in paramiko module in python scripts in remote machine

Tags: python, sudo, paramiko, remote-server

My scenario is I need to login to a remote machine and then do a sudo to another account like (`sudo su anotheract`) and then run the other required command.

But I am able to successfully connect to remote machine using below script. But the scripts hangs in the line where I am executing the sudo command(`sudo su anotheract`)

Can you please help me find the fix for this code?

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(hostname='XX.XXX.XX.XX',port=22, username='myname',password='XXXXX')

ssh.exec_command=("sudo su anotheract")

stdout,stdin,stderr=ssh.exec_command("java -jar /usr/share/XXX/LogR.jar")

print stdout.readlines()
```

Answer (score 2):

One (not very safe) way to do it is to pipe the password in. The caveat is that the user that you are using to connect to the box using paramiko should have sudo rights.

For example:

```
supass = 'some_pass'

stdout, stdin, stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo %s | sudo -S anotheract' % supass)
```

Again, this is not a very safe implementation but gets the job done in a jiffy.

Comment: I tried your methid and 'm getting `standard in must be a tty
`

Comment: @YogeeshSeralathan paramiko.SSHClient().exec_command('your cmd', get_pty=True)

Answer (score -1):

```
import pxssh
ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
ssh.login('host', 'user', 'password')
ssh.sendline("sudo su anotheract")
ssh.prompt('yourrootpassword')
```

And in paramiko on most linux systems you cant do sudo commands thats because sudo expect commands from tty and then it isnt raise exception, but you can try method invokeshell, but I used paramiko many years ago I dont remember what was been wrong with it. If you want send various commands on shell you could use pxssh.

Comment: hi tried using PXssh but no help dueing the sudo command it is hanged same issue

Comment: what operating system installed on your remote machine?

Comment: @denis How to do that using `paramiko` in linux ?

Answer (score -2):

It can hangen because `sudo` waits for password. Try to add `NOPASSWD:` statement to the `/etc/sudoers`.

```
user    ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/true
```

Also it is impossible to change user using `su` and then continue do to something after `su` is finished. When `su` is finished, you are back to your original shell of the original user.

So you need to run all commands with `sudo`:

```
stdout,stdin,stderr = ssh.exec_command=("sudo -u anotheract java -jar /usr/share/XXX/LogR.jar")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply  HI actually NOPASSWD was already there in /etc/sudoers ,i have checked also the same i.e if i am running the the command manually by doing SSH to the remoter server and running the sudo su anotheract ,it is not asking the password and going thorough.facing the issue only through the script..

Comment: Very well we have party: "Everybody ROOT tonight"

Comment: @Denis: Why do you think so? How can you get rootrights for everybody (and even for `user`) using this line? Do you know the meaning of this line?

Comment: @Igor Chubin Ok I don saw what you set nopasswd on true, but anyway it doesnt work

Comment: @Denis: It works; I've just checked it on my system. But back to your phrase "Everybody ROOT tonight": why have you written "everybody"? Where have you seen "everybody" here?

Comment: hi iam facing the same issue is there any work around for remote ssh and sudo or running any other scripts  using paramiko